# lpinfo not found in docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm using the `python:slim-buster` image, and trying to install a printer so that it's usable by my containers. I'm following [these great directions](https://www.baitando.com/it/2017/12/12/install-dymo-labelwriter-on-headless-linux) (which worked on my host machine -- well actually on my linux VM that I'm considering as the host for the docker environment), but the docker container can't find `lpinfo` or `lpstat` or any other printer commands. I checked `/usr/sbin` and it's not in there either.

How do I fix this? Or is this maybe not necessary to use a printer in docker?

Updates after some comments:

1. I am indeed using `python:3.8.0-slim-buster` image. I'm not tied to that image, for sure. I'd started with an alpine image but that uses apk not apt, and apk doesn't have the print driver I need.
2. I'm not even tied into using Python. Node would be fine with me as well. I don't know what libraries I'll be using to print -- I was working on getting the printer talking to Docker first before I incorporated anything into the project code. The previous step was getting printing to work from the terminal of my Linux VM (on my Windows laptop), and I figured the next step would be getting printing to work from the terminal of my Docker container (via `docker exec`). Perhaps I'm going about this wrong and my real question is "how to print from a docker container?"

Comment: (1) If you want tools that aren't in the image, you need to add them. If the image is based on a Debian-style base (which `buster-slim` is; I'm assuming `slim-buster` was a mistype), that means calling `apt` or `dpkg` in your Dockerfile; if it's built on a RPM-based base, typically `yum`; etc

Comment: (2) Whether you need those tools to print from Python depends entirely on what interfaces your printer offers, and what libraries you're using to do the printing (and whether it natively supports the protocols in question). If you have a Python library that outputs Postscript over the wire, and a printer that can be fed Postscript over a socket, there you are -- you have all the moving parts, nothing else needed. But if you don't tell us what Python libraries you're using, and what interfaces or protocols your printer supports, it's not really an answerable question.

Comment: I'd also strongly (strongly!) suggest _not_ trying to install an IPP server inside your Docker container at all. It won't be able to use `usb://` addresses in CUPS, f/e. Better to just have it connect over the network to the copy of CUPS on your host, which _already has_ a working connection to your printer. What it takes to do that depends on which Python libraries you're using to print, which again you haven't said.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the comments. I've updated my question with some of the things you mentioned.

Comment: Printing from inside Docker sounds like a weird way to arrange things. What's preventing you from producing whatever you want to produce inside the Docker image, then print from the host computer?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure what you mean. It could simply be over my head. All my software runs in Docker, with a web front end accessed from Chrome on the host Linux machine. I want a "print" button in my GUI that sends info to the printer. Honestly anything I've said about *how* that happens is an assumption and could fully be wrong. Happy to be set right!

Comment: So if Chrome is running on the host Linux machine, why don't you print from Chrome? Quick googling suggests `window.print()` should do that.

Comment: What tripleee said. It's certainly _possible_ to do a print job from the server side rather than the client side, but printing from the client side is more commonly the right thing to do (after all, someone viewing a web interface is more likely to have access to the printer they want to use than the server producing that interface is!); and that way, you don't need to set up the server to have access to the printer at all. Sometimes this means producing a PDF or a printer-optimized version of your HTML with the content to print, or just having both printer- and display-targeted stylesheets.

Comment: I understand now. But once I produce that PDF, how do I send it to the printer without the user having to open it and print themselves?

Comment: Javascript. Same thing your bank website does when you hit print with a statement. The details depend on the browser in use -- typically it'll open up a print dialog with the default printer, ready for the user to press enter to accept.